# Rcpparmadillo matrixproduct performance

Tags: r, rcpp

Can someone explain to me why the calculations becomes so much slower when I add `arma::mat P(X * arma::inv(X.t() * X) * X.t());` to my code. The mean grew with a factor 164 last time I benchmarked the code.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
List test1(DataFrame data, Language formula, String y_name) {
  Function model_matrix("model.matrix");
  NumericMatrix x_rcpp = model_matrix(formula, data);
  NumericVector y_rcpp = data[y_name];
  arma::mat X(x_rcpp.begin(), x_rcpp.nrow(), x_rcpp.ncol());
  arma::colvec Y(y_rcpp.begin(), y_rcpp.size());

  arma::colvec coef = inv(X.t() * X) * X.t() * Y;
  arma::colvec resid = Y - X * coef;
  arma::colvec fitted = X * coef;

  DataFrame data_res = DataFrame::create(_["Resid"] = resid,
                    _["Fitted"] = fitted);

  return List::create(_["Results"] = coef,
                      _["Data"] = data_res);
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
List test2(DataFrame data, Language formula, String y_name) {
  Function model_matrix("model.matrix");
  NumericMatrix x_rcpp = model_matrix(formula, data);
  NumericVector y_rcpp = data[y_name];
  arma::mat X(x_rcpp.begin(), x_rcpp.nrow(), x_rcpp.ncol());
  arma::colvec Y(y_rcpp.begin(), y_rcpp.size());

  arma::colvec coef = inv(X.t() * X) * X.t() * Y;
  arma::colvec resid = Y - X * coef;
  arma::colvec fitted = X * coef;

  arma::mat P(X * arma::inv(X.t() * X) * X.t());

  DataFrame data_res = DataFrame::create(_["Resid"] = resid,
                                         _["Fitted"] = fitted);

  return List::create(_["Results"] = coef,
                      _["Data"] = data_res);
}

/*** R
data <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(10000), X1 = rnorm(10000), X2 = rnorm(10000), X3 = rnorm(10000))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(test1(data, Y~X1+X2+X3, "Y"),
                               test2(data, Y~X1+X2+X3, "Y"), times = 10)
  */
```

Best regards,
Jakob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is awfully close to [`fastLm()`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/src/fastLm.cpp) which I revised many times over the years. From that we can draw a few conclusions:

1. Don't X (X' X)^1 X' directly. Use `solve()`.
2. Don't *ever* work off a formula object. Use a matrix and vector for `X` and `y`.

Here is [benchmark example](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/examples/fastLm.r) illustrating how parsing the formula destroys all gains from the matrix algebra.

As an aside, R itself has pivoted operations for rank-deficient matrix. That help with deformed matrices; in many "normal" cases you should be ok.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is because I'm currently working on a new implementation, which allows piping and is inspired by the tidyverse package. I'm a huge fan of the ```fastlm()``` function, but this implementation is aimed at economic students who don't have any programming experience.  So even though I have to make slower implementation due to the formula inefficiency, I would like to use the formula. So would you recommend to use ```model.matrix()``` and then use ```fastlm()```?

Comment: My conclusion from the benchmark (link two) is that if you insist on using a formula, you don't need to bother with the C++ side for the fit.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. Not entirely sure why the speed increase outside of a few notes that I've made. So, be warned.

Consider the *n* being used here is 10000 with the *p* being 3.

Let's look at the operations requested. We'll start with the `coef` or beta_hat operation:

```
Beta_[p x 1] = (X^T_[p x n] * X_[n x p])^(-1) * X^T_[p x n] * Y_[n x 1]
```

Looking at the `P` or projection / hat matrix:

```
P_[n x n] = X_[n x p] * (X^T_[p x n] * X_[n x p])^(-1) * X^T_[p x n]
```

So, the N matrix here is sufficiently *larger* than the prior matrix. Matrix multiplication is generally governed by O(n^3) (the naive schoolbook multiplication). So, potentially, this can explain the large increment in time.

Outside of that, there are repetitive calculations involving

```
(X^T_[p x n] * X_[n x p])^(-1) * X^T_[p x n]
```

within `test2` causing it to be recomputed. The main issue here is the inverse being the most expensive operation.

Also, regarding the use of [`inv`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#inv) the API entry indicates that:

> - if matrix A is know to be symmetric positive definite, using inv_sympd() is faster
> - if matrix A is know to be diagonal, use inv( diagmat(A) )
> - to solve a system of linear equations, such as Z = inv(X)*Y, using solve() is faster and more accurate

The third point is particular of interest in this case as it gives a more optimized routine for `inv(X.t() * X)*X.t()` => `solve(X.t() * X, X.t())`